# ZABBIX to control access to wi-fi?

Tags: wifi, zabbix

I have a wi-fi network and must manage access to the Internet by mobile devices (smartphone and tablet). I need users with configurable levels of permissions, traffic limits, speed, connection time, ability to generate reports of visited sites, block some specific sites and some other things.

A friend recommended me using Zabbix for that, but to me he did not understand what the tool can do, I would use RADIUSdesk or similar.

**So, who is wrong? Me or him?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zabbix is monitoring tool, not Wifi management tool. You can use it, but you will need to code a lot of functionalities for Wifi management. Definitely it's not good idea.